# Which special characters are safe to use in url?

Tags: url

Which special characters are safe to use in url?

Comment: It would be far quicker and easier to ask which special characters are *unsafe* to use in a URL (as per Andreas Bonini's answer below).

Comment: Asking what is unsafe is as hard to answer: Any non-ascii character needs to be percent-encoded.

Comment: @neo: no it doesn't :O

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The safe characters are `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, and `_` `-` (underscore and minus), that besides the reserved characters which are used for the parameters.

Other characters will give problems to varying degrees, or with varying frequency. For example: if one parameter is an array `?param=array[content]` it will show a URL with the square brackets URL-encoded, which look ugly and impossible to dictate.

But the problem is not only that it's ugly. Let's say you have a JPEG with a character in the name other than the safer ones; many times the browser will be unable to download it, getting a 404. This is a problem for older browsers and some mobile browsers.

How can we test this?

- put a bunch of images/js/css with the characters you want to test in the names on a public page with many visitors
- Make the 404 page send you an email every time it gets a hit

I have an inbox with 14,000 emails proving my point.

Comment: well, instead of "safe characters" I would say "extremely safe characters" -- the spec allows more, but I agree with you that it's better to be conservative here.

Comment: What's wrong with period?

Comment: can you also explain why `.` isn't a safe character?

Comment: I see edits that could improve this answer, but I hate to remove @JeffAtwood as the last person to edit it 

Comment: please feel free to edit @iconoclast!

Answer (score 18):

The following characters have special meaning in the path component of your URL (the path component is everything before the '?'):

```
  ";" | "/" | "?"
```

In addition to those, the following characters have special meaning in the query part of your URL (everything after '?'). Therefore, if they are after the '?' you need to escape them:

```
  ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
```

For a more in-depth explanation, see the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

Comment: Of course, just for clarity, this answer is the opposite of the question. The question asks for which characters are safe, not those which are unsafe. Since it's hard to answer the original question robustly, the question should probably be edited to ask it the other way around and match this answer.

Answer (score 7):

[RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) is actually obsolete and was superseded by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

The unreserved special characters (safe to use without encoding) (other than letters and digits) are:

`-`  `.` `_` and `~`

Comment: From RFC 3986.: unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"

Answer (score 6):

This question popped up first, of course, when I googled up "URL safe characters", as most people would. I think it's worthy to put up a straightforward answer to a concise question. [From the horse's— ugh, RFC2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#section-2.3)— I mean, Sir Timothy's mouth:

> ```
> 2.3. Unreserved Characters
>
>    Data characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
>    purpose are called unreserved.  These include upper and lower case
>    letters, decimal digits, and a limited set of punctuation marks and
>    symbols.
>
>       unreserved  = alphanum | mark
>
>       mark        = "-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")"
>
>    Unreserved characters can be escaped without changing the semantics
>    of the URI, but this should not be done unless the URI is being used
>    in a context that does not allow the unescaped character to appear.
> ```

"Upper and lower case letters" in this context are understood as [defined earlier in the section 1.6 of the same standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#section-1.6):

> ```
> The following definitions are common to many elements:
>
>    alpha    = lowalpha | upalpha
>
>    lowalpha = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i" |
>               "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" |
>               "s" | "t" | "u" | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z"
>
>    upalpha  = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" | "I" |
>               "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" | "N" | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" |
>               "S" | "T" | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z"
>
>    digit    = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" |
>               "8" | "9"
>
>    alphanum = alpha | digit
> ```

So the answer is, URL-safe characters are good old ASCII-7 Latin characters `A` through `Z` in lower and upper case, decimal digits `0` through `9`, and a handful of non-alphanumerics explicitly enumerated in the `mark` production rule of the grammar in Sec. 2.3.

---

If the question is to be understood about the HTTP/HTTPS UR**L** (note that RFC2396 defines the UR**I**), the *semantic* treatment of the RFC2396 *syntax* as resource locators for the HTTP[S] protocol is currently standardised by [RFC7230, Sec. 2.7](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7230.html#section-2.7). Nevertheless, inferring that the set of "URL-safe" characters is larger than that defined by the RFC2396 from the observation that they are not treated specially in RFC7230 Sec. 2.7 would not be a future-proof move; a possible future RFC7230 update may ascribe semantics to more characters that are outside of the "URL-safe" RFC2396 set, rendering such an inference *ex statu quo* invalid.

**TL;DR**, it is the safest and future-proof approach to treat the set of URL-safe characters defined in RFC2396 as the largest possible and non-extensible, and not extend it with those that are *currently* okay/safe/non-special per RFC7230: this may change. The RFC2396 set, in contrast, cannot.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here are good, but there is one more exception I think is worth mentioning - non-english characters. Referencing [this SF question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/142793/can-i-use-the-character-n-in-a-sub-domain), characters like ñ (as in Español) are perfectly legitimate, IF they have been encoded in your DNS correctly.

You have to use [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) within your DNS to get them to resolve in modern browsers (the entry for español is `xn--espaol-zwa`) but these are now perfectly safe to use in domain names, as they're easy for non-english-speakers to type as well.