# URLs posted with @ in the path are not autolinked properly, are they valid?

Tags: url

I have a site where users post comments.  Often, those comments have URLs to a video streaming site with URLs in the following format:

[image]

My site does not link the latter part comprising @57m58s which leads them to that specific part of the video.

I tried to determine if this URL format is indeed valid by going through the [RFC for URL format](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).  I'm also trying to find out if it has ramifications from the [security perspective](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/498/which-special-characters-are-safe-to-use-in-url) because these are added as comments in the site. (The comments don't allow users to add HTML content).

Is implementing a filter to ensure that the URL is fully linked inclusive of `@time` valid?  Could it be a security concern?

Comment: Based on your profile, I'm guessing this is a problem with Drupal.   I created a [Drupal sandbox](http://s1cb50a8b5d36d6c.s3.simplytest.me/node/1) to test it.   [Here is the screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s735d.png).   Drupal does not link the `@57m58s` portion of the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort you put into this! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL with an `@` in the path **is valid**.  [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) talks about `@` in section 2.2.   It is a "reserved character".  That means that it is allowed in the URL, but that it *might* have special meaning depending on the spec for that particular URL.   In the case of HTTP URLs, there is no special meaning for `@` in the path portion.   Therefore, it is a legitimate character that may be used by webmasters.

Any software which attempts to use heuristics to identify URLs and autolink them should allow an `@` in the path of a HTTP URL.

There are some possible security implications from allowing the path of a linked URL to contain `@`:

- The `@` does have special meaning in the domain name portion of a HTTP URL.  There it specifies the user name and password for basic authentication.   Auto linking a URL like `http://user:pass@example.com/` could cause users that click it to automatically log into another site with the specified user and password.
- Auto linking a URL like `www.example.com@foo.example.net` could be problematic.  Is that an email address?   Is that an attempt to get somebody to log into `foo.example.net` as the user `www.example.com`?

In my opinion, these security concerns are minor and would be mitigated by ensuring that any implementation restricts the allowed `@` to the portion *after* the domain name and slash.  StackExchange sites *do* autolink URLs with `@` in the path.   So doing so is not without precedent.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/can-i-use-an-at-symbol-inside-urls), <strike>@ is a reserved symbol and should not be used directly in URLs. However, it should work when URL encoded.</strike>

Correction: @ is a legal character for the path component, and should work. Nevertheless, if reality disagrees with theory, trying a practical solution isn't a bad idea.

Therefore, a form filter that converts raw @ to %40 might solve your problem.

Comment: According to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737890/1591669) in the linked question, `@` can be used directly (i.e., unencoded) in the path.

Comment: Res ipsa loquitur. Raw @ isn't working properly on the asker's site. RFC-compliant percent encoding addresses his concerns.

Comment: 1. We don’t know *why* it is not working. Using `@` without percent-encoding works perfectly fine for various other sites (including twitter.com). It might be the case that percent-encoding helps the OP in his specific context (which we don’t know yet), but it’s not correct to state that `@` "should not be used directly".  2. It is *also* RFC-compliant not to percent-encode `@` in the path.