# Which special characters are safe and unreserved to use in the complete URL?

Tags: url, http

After reading [these](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/498/which-special-characters-are-safe-to-use-in-url) answers and some Googling I couldn't find a precise answer. [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#section-2.3) states that these characters are unreserved

`"-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")"`

How can `.` be unreserved? Isn't that the base of a domain? eg. www`.`google`.`com/index`.`html

Further, it is mentioned in the same [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#section-2.4.3) that these characters are unwise as some services might use them as delimiters. I've never seen these being used in such s way. Have I just not been paying attention?

`` "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`" ``

---

My intention is to build a redirect service which would anonymize resources. say `location.com/Vzb16-8es9a/Gk7sL3j@+q`. I want to generate these 10 char random strings without causing misinterpretations on the receiving side, which could really be anything. I close to understanding until I read the `period` is unreserved.

I hope someone can shed some light on these as I am thoroughly confused as what's safe and what's not
.

Comment: The characters reserved in the domain portion of the URL are different than those reserved in the path portion of the URL.  It looks like you are mostly concerned with the path, correct?

Comment: You are correct, I'm mostly concerned about the portion denoting path, *however the .html could exist in the path. I wouldn't want . to cause undesired results

Comment: Why do you need such long URLs with so many characters?  Even if you stuck to just the 26 letters in both cases + 10 digits, 7 characters would give you 3.5 trillion possible URLs.

Comment: 10 characters per step on a 2 step structure, surely that isn't too long? ie. domain.com/10chars/10chars

Comment: Way too long unless you have some reason I'm not seeing.

Comment: For your use case there are enough different chars without resorting to "special" chars. It's not really a case as to which characters are technically permitted in the URL-path, but using any special non-word characters are potentially going to cause problems for users copy/pasting/sharing (and even typing) these URLs.